# How can you change a Label's color at runtime in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, label, mxml

I get the following error:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property color through a reference with static
type mx.controls:Label.
```

The thing about that is that, in the MXML, color is an attribute of Label.  But if I try to say something like:

```
lblUpgrade.color = "#000000";
```

it throws this error.  I've been trying to find a work-around for the last 45 minutes.  How can I set this at runtime?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html) does not have a `color` property, rather it has a color style which can be set like so:

```
lblUpgrade.setStyle("color","#000000");
```

Answer (score 5):

Styles are accessed like this in as3

```
lblUpgrade.setStyle("color","#000000");
```

Answer (score 4):

color is a style not a property, you set it using `setStyle`. Also with as3 you use `0x` instead of `#` for the color, but maybe that works for styles.

lblUpgrade.setStyle("color", "0x000000");

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I've been struggling for 45 minutes AFTER I found this post. I'm using Adobe CS6 (don't ask why!) and the only way that finally works for me is this:

```
/* Create a new TextFormat object, 
which allows you to set multiple text properties at a time. */ 

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tf.color = 0xFF0000; 

/* Apply this specific text format (red text) to the Label instance. */ 
a_label.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

Hope this helps someone. Source: [Adobe Help Center](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f49.html)

You can also use TextFormat to change other properties like [Font, Size](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/705517?start=0&tstart=0) etc.